# python create interchangeable strings

Tags: python, string

lets say I have 2 strings that are interchangeable, like a full word and it's abbreviation: `'max'` and `'maximum'`

I would like to set it so that they respond the same, for example if i have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'max':10,'a':5,'b':9}
```

`d['maximum']` will return `10`

**is this even remotely possible?**

note:

these two strings could be `'dog'` and `'cat'`, they do not have to be related.

what I am asking is if I could do something like:

```
a = 'a' or 'b'
```

that way the two strings are interchangeable. I do understand that above is not correct syntax, I am just curious if anything like it is possible

Comment: I am not asking specifically as a dictionary. I am asking if it is possible to have any time one string is referenced in my code to have it work as if either string is referenced...a dictionary was a good example and that is why I used it

Comment: the abbreviation was also just for a real world example

Comment: I think you need to qualify this a little better ... interchangable in what sense?  If you want them to be interchangeable in a dictionary, the answer is no.  `"max"` and `"maximum"` aren't the same string.  You could subclass dict and make sure to only use one or the other ... but that only catches the dictionary case (and it doesn't work with literals)....

Comment: @mgilson: exactly my question though, I am asking if I could have a variable act as multiple strings, where it would go down the line somewhat like nested `try` and `except`s

Comment: Dict if the best way to do this({'a':'b', 'dog':'cat'}), if you want two way mapping use [bidict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict‎).

Comment: the only way you can possibly do this the way you want to is to write a program that modifies your source code changing all "maximum" to "max" or vice-versa.... will be complicated program to ensure you don't change maximum's in wrong places that have nothing to do with your dicts.

It's either "max" or "maximum", it's encouraging bad coding and bad practices using 2 different names to access the same variable.

Comment: the idea for this is not in my coding, it is for human error. I am creating a plug-in that enables syntax abbreviation on the client side and was trying to think of an easy way to catch errors, but I'll just iterate and check with some nested try and excepts

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using two dicts:

```
>>> key_dic = {'maximum':'max', 'minimum':'min'}
>>> d = {'max':10,'a':5,'b':9, 'min':-1}
def get_value(key):
    return d[key_dic.get(key, key)]
... 
>>> get_value('maximum')
10
>>> get_value('max')
10
>>> get_value('min')
-1
>>> get_value('minimum')
-1
```

Comment: please read my edited question...the dictionary was simply an example...the real question is if I can somehow assign a variable to respond to more than one string

Comment: @RyanSaxe For variables the short answer is NO, you can't make a variable point to two different objects at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert it into a function, class or something similar.

```
d_array = {'max':10,'a':5,'b':9}

def d(keyword):
    if keyword == "maximum":
        keyword = "max"
    return d_array[keyword]


>>>print d("maximum")
10
```

Comment: please read my edited question...the dictionary was simply an example...the real question is if I can somehow assign a variable to respond to more than one string